# how to calculate diameter and length change from volume change for a hollow cylinder?

Tags: volume

I have a cylindrical material with a hole going through its center all along the larger dimension (length). I know the dimensions and the volume of the cylinder at temperature T1. Now, if I heat it up to another temperature T2, then I can calculate the volume change from the volume expansion coefficient of the material, which I already know. But, how to calculate the new dimensions (diameter, length) of the cylinder at that elevated temperature? I mean, how the diameter and length change would relate to the volume change? Any help will be highly appreciated ...

Thanks
Naz

Comment: Perhaps [this might help.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/thexp2.html) Use the volume of the cylinder for V.

Answer (score 2):

Every dimension of the cylinder will increase by the same proportion - let's call it x.  Then the volume increases by a factor of $(1+x)^3.$  You know the latter, so just take the cube root.